Working wife's obedience
Assalamualaikum alaikum wa rahmatullahi wabrakatuhu
Is it permissible for the wife to work from home without husband's permission ?
if the wife is working from home and husband commands her not to work by giving a reason that her work sometimes require interaction with non mehrams on calls or in meetings for work purposes.
Does she have to obey him in this case ??
